# Java Stream API map argument

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have some misunderstanding about Java 8 static method references.

The following is a correct statement:

```
Stream.of("aaa", "bbb", "cccc").map(String::length);
```

AFAIK `map` requires a `Function<T, R> interface` as an argument with method similar to:

```
R apply(T t);
```

However, the `length()` method of `String` class doesn't accept any arguments:

```
public int length() {
    return value.length;
}
```

1) How does it correlate with `apply` method which needs an argument `T t`?

2) If I write `String::someMethod` doesn't it mean that `someMethod` should be static (since I'm calling it by class name, not by an object reference)?

Thank you!

Comment: The object instance upon which the method is to be invoked is that missing argument you are looking for. Note how you are mapping over a stream of String instances.

Comment: In this situation just replace a method reference with a lambda expression for a better understanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `String::someMethod` doesn't mean the method has to be static. It could be either a static method, or an instance method that would be executed on some `String` instance. That instance would serve as an implicit argument of the single method of the functional interface implemented by that method reference.

Therefore `String::length` does have a single argument - the `String` instance on which the `length` method will be called.

`String::length` is equivalent to the lambda expression `(String s) -> s.length()` (or just `s -> s.length()`).

When you write `Stream.of("aaa", "bbb", "cccc").map(String::length)`, the `length()` method would be executed for each element of your `Stream` (assuming you add some terminal operation that causes `map` to be evaluated on these elements) which would transform your `Stream<String>` to a `Stream<Integer>`.

Answer (score 3):

When you expand your lambdas/method references to anonymous inner class, it makes things easier to understand. Your statement translates to something like this when you replace method references with anonymous class:

```
Stream.of("aaa", "bbb", "cccc").map(new Function<String, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(String s) {
        return s.length();
    }
});
```

As you can see here input is the String and it returns string length which is a Integer. And it adheres to the `Function` functional Interface definition that you mentioned.